# Install pyenv by zip file instead git clone and curl

Tags: pyenv

There are some security issues, so the server is not open to external connections.

Therefore, I cannot use the suggested methods of installing pyenv through curl or git clone on the official website. Instead, I downloaded the pyenv files using the git clone command on my local machine, packaged them with zip, and then transferred them to the server.

However, I have been having trouble using pyenv commands after installing it this way, even though I can see the pyenv path in $PATH. The commands just won't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry5Yk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xthhw.png)

I've spent all day trying to solve this problem. Can you please help me?

I have studied the office website to sloving this problem
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#advanced-configuration